# Persisting drawn frames in Gloss

Tags: haskell, graphics, gloss

I've been messing around with [Gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gloss/1.7.8.2/doc/html/Graphics-Gloss.html#t%3aDisplay) for a little bit, getting a feel for it, and I really like it!

I'm having one problem though, and that is that I'm not sure how to persist drawings for more than one frame. I can draw one Picture at a time, but I'm not sure how to keep them on the screen. I can always keep a list of Pictures and display those, but that seems like it could be very inefficient, so I wanted to check if there was a better way to do it. I've been going through the documentation and haven't found anything.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Gloss has grown significantly in the past year, you can't.  The mental model is simple, you have some code that mutates the state, and every period you have something that renders the new state.  No one is saying this is efficient, but this was developed as an educational library.